# Python-Using Random Choice to Prompt User-Adventure Game

Tags: python

I am having trouble with my code. When running my code and select the no option to play the game again the game ends. But, I am having trouble with my code when I select the yes option to play again, it does not automatically go back to play the game again. What am I do wrong?

```
import time
import random
response = []

action_list = ["option1", "option2"]
print(random.choice(action_list))


def print_pause(message_to_print):
    print(message_to_print)
    time.sleep(2)


def valid_input(prompt, option1, option2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 == response:
            break
        elif option2 == response:
            break
        else:
            print_pause("Sorry, I do not follow.")
    return response


def intro():
    print_pause("You have approached your apartment building.")
    print_pause("You noticed a shadow nearby.")
    print_pause("Should you run and drive off to the nearest safe location?")
    print_pause("Should you face your fears and attack?")


def adventure_panic():
    response = valid_input("Please make your decision. "
                           "Would you like run or attack?\n",
                           "run", "attack")
    if "run" in response:
        print_pause("Run towards your car and drive to a safe location.")
        print_pause("Call the police to inform them what you saw.")
    elif "attack" in response:
        print_pause("Slowly walk towards the nearby shadow.")
        print_pause("Grab your pocketknife and pepper spray.")
        print_pause("As you come closer to the shadow.")
        print_pause("You find out that it is just a cat")
    print_pause("Congratulations! You're safe.")
    play_again()


def play_again():
    response = valid_input("Would you like to play again? "
                           "Please say 'yes' or 'no'.\n",
                           "yes", "no")
    if "yes" == response:
        print_pause("Great, let's play again!")
        intro()
        adventure_panic()
    elif "no" == response:
        print_pause("Ok, exit game!")
        exit(0)


def play_panic(): 
    intro()
    # adventure_panic()

play_panic()
```

Comment: This will cause stack overflow if the user is patient enough..

Comment: After uncommenting the line in `play_panic()` it works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I am not seeing where play_panic() is commented out. Are you referring to the last code?

Comment: `# adventure_panic()` in the function `play_panic()`

Comment: It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In def play_panic() you only call intro() try to change it to def play_panic(): intro() adventure_panic() play_again()

Answer (score 0):

When I ran your code, I didnt even get to the play again function. Instead of calling the adventure_panic() function in play_panic(), you registered it as a comment with a "#". You  also didnt call the play_again function. The actual function works properly for me

```py
import time
import random
response = []

action_list = ["option1", "option2"]
print(random.choice(action_list))


def print_pause(message_to_print):
    print(message_to_print)
    time.sleep(2)


def valid_input(prompt, option1, option2):
    while True:
        response = input(prompt).lower()
        if option1 == response:
            break
        elif option2 == response:
            break
        else:
            print_pause("Sorry, I do not follow.")
    return response


def intro():
    print_pause("You have approached your apartment building.")
    print_pause("You noticed a shadow nearby.")
    print_pause("Should you run and drive off to the nearest safe location?")
    print_pause("Should you face your fears and attack?")


def adventure_panic():
    response = valid_input("Please make your decision. "
                           "Would you like run or attack?\n",
                           "run", "attack")
    if "run" in response:
        print_pause("Run towards your car and drive to a safe location.")
        print_pause("Call the police to inform them what you saw.")
    elif "attack" in response:
        print_pause("Slowly walk towards the nearby shadow.")
        print_pause("Grab your pocketknife and pepper spray.")
        print_pause("As you come closer to the shadow.")
        print_pause("You find out that it is just a cat")
    print_pause("Congratulations! You're safe.")
    play_again()


def play_again():
    response = valid_input("Would you like to play again? "
                           "Please say 'yes' or 'no'.\n",
                           "yes", "no")
    if "yes" == response:
        print_pause("Great, let's play again!")
        intro()
        adventure_panic()
    elif "no" == response:
        print_pause("Ok, exit game!")
        exit(0)


def play_panic(): 
    intro()
    adventure_panic() #remove the # so that adventure_panic() is called. If there is a # python registers it as a comment and it is ignored
    play_again() #calls the play again function

play_panic()
```